# How do I get a reference to the current Promise within then()

Tags: javascript, promise, cancellation

In the code below, I would like to check that the callback is executing from the latestRequest, so I am checking `thisPromise` to see if it is the same as `latestRequest`. Obviously `thisPromise` doesn't work. Is there a way to get the current Promise?

```
let latestRequest = MyLib
  .retrieve(getFilteredQuery(filters, queries, user))
  .then(res => {
    // Checking whether this is the latest request handler
    if (latestRequest === thisPromise) {
      updateData(res)
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

My use case is for handling requests from an API. I only want the data to be updated for the latest request. The requests can take very different times to return, and sometimes an earlier request is coming back later and overwriting the latest request. If you know a good way to handle this, please let me know.

Comment: I'd suggest just assigning a counter to each request (somewhere in the scope of the request) and keeping track of the highest counter that you've gotten results from and then you can ignore any older requests (lower counter values) that come in late.  That also seems a lot more bulletproof too than trying to compare promises.  Remember, a promise chain consists of several promises as each call to `new Promise()` or `.then()` creates a new promise.  It isn't just one promise in a chain.  The code you show has multiple promises active in it.

Comment: There is only a single `latestPromise` in your code. Please show the full code that creates multiple promises.

Comment: @Bergi I have included example code, simplified. Think of that code as being within a function that can be called from other places within the app.

Comment: Well, then just keep one global `latestPromise` and multiple local `thisPromise` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method of obtaining a reference to the promise object `.then` was called on from within the handler supplied by `.then`.

One suggestion is to assign the handler a sequence number and check if it is the last one issued, from within a closure. Untested example:

```
let latestRequestId = 0;

let checkLatest = ()=> {
    let thisRequest = ++latestRequestId;
    return (res=>{
    // Checking whether this is the latest request handler
    if (latestRequestId === thisRequest) {
      updateData(res)
    }
  })
}

let latestRequest = MyLib
  .retrieve(getFilteredQuery(filters, queries, user))
  .then(checkLatest())
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Comment: You have two `latestRequest` variables in there

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, have fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Implementation within a closure:

```
const run = (() => {
  let currentPromise;

  return () => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // run an asynchronous process and resolve like resolve(results)
    })
    .then(results => {
      if (p === currentPromise) {
        // process results here
      }
    })

    currentPromise = p;
  }
})()
```

Similar alternative using `class`:

```
class Request {
  static #currentPromise;

  static run() {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // run an asynchronous process and resolve like resolve(results)
    })
    .then(results => {
      if (p === Request.#currentPromise) {
        // process results here
      }
    })

    Request.#currentPromise = p;
  }
}
```

You could test by implementing with simulated latency:

```
const run = (() => {
  let currentPromise;

  return (timeout) => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(_ => resolve(timeout), timeout);
    })
    .then(data => {
      if (p === currentPromise) {
        console.log('latest request', data);
      }
    })

    currentPromise = p;
  }
})()

run(1000); // 1s request
run( 500);
run(  10); // last request, 0.1s
```

Comment: Don't use `class` syntax if you only have static properties

Comment: `class` can offer encapsulation with private properties, if needed.

Comment: A simple IIFE or just a module scope could do the same. No need to abuse `class` syntax as a namespace.